# How to know running states of a cpp program with Visual Studio SDK

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-sdk

i want to  do statistics on cpp programming action so i decide to develop a plugin with Visual Studio SDK. Now i encounter a problem. I want to know the running state of the cpp program. e.g.  when user launch the program? when the program end? or whether the program runs successfully.

i have read a part of api references on msdn. i have just found dte.debugger and Ivsdebugger to get debug info.but i cannot find api to get normal run states.

can someone give me an idea? thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

i have solved it.  in VS,  debug run or normal run  is treated as the same. they all trigger debug event.  i can tell normal run from debug run by analysing the debug target.